# Regular Expression backtracks until overflow in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, backtracking

The following expression:

```
^(#ifdef FEATURE)+?\s*$((\r\n.*?)*^(#endif)+\s*[\/\/]*\s*(end of)*\s*FEATURE)+?$
```

Overrides the matching buffer when running my compiled .Jar file.

The matching string can be similar to:

> this is a junk line
>
> **#ifdef FEATURE**
>   **#endif // end of FEATURE**
>
> this is a junk line
>
> **#ifdef FEATURE**
>
> **this is a junk line that should be matched: HOLasduiqwhei & // FEATURE fjfefj**
>         **#endif // h**
>
> **#endif FEATURE**
>
> this is a junk line

So, the bold strings should match. The error is as follows:

```
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Unknown Source)
```

Any backtracking avoiding strategy/improvement of the expression is welcome. I have tried the atomic groups `(?>)` but doesn't simplify, for some reason.

The code is the following:

public String strip(String text) {

```
    ArrayList<String> patterns=new ArrayList<String>();
    patterns=readFile("Disabled_Features.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < patterns.size(); ++i)
    {

      Pattern todoPattern = Pattern.compile("^#ifdef "+patterns.get(i)+"((?:\\r?\\n(?!#endif (?:// end of )?"+patterns.get(i)+"$).*)*)\\r?\\n#endif (?:// end of )?"+patterns.get(i)+"$",Pattern.MULTILINE); 

      Matcher m = todoPattern.matcher(text);
      text = m.replaceAll("");
    }
    return text;        
}
```

Comment: Check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9n7HPJ/1).

Comment: Hello, your expression still gives me an overflow.

Comment: Please post the code used to match the regex

Comment: Sorry, the function block is the following: check post again.

Comment: erg... I mean the java code. I have update my answer, and tried the code written by @WiktorStribiżew. No overflow.

Comment: Do not use regex, use `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the code written by @Wiktor and works pretty well

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "this is a junk line\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "#ifdef FEATURE \n" + 
        "#endif // end of FEATURE\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "this is a junk line\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "#ifdef FEATURE\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "this is a junk line that should be matched: HOLasduiqwhei & // FEATURE fjfefj #endif // h\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "#endif FEATURE\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "this is a junk line";

    // this version does not use Pattern.MULTILINE, this should reduce the backtraking
    Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("\\n#ifdef FEATURE((?:\\r?\\n(?!#endif (?:// end of )?FEATURE).*)*)\\r?\\n#endif (?:// end of )?FEATURE").matcher(text);
    while (matcher2.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher2.group());
    }

  }
}
```

This let me to think that your problem is due to the size of input file.

So, in case your file is too big, you could implement the input as a `CharSequence`, so you could wrap your large text files. Why? Because building a `Matcher` from a `Pattern` takes a `CharSequence` as an argument.

https://github.com/fge/largetext

Comment: As far as I can see, my expression has no apparent open parentheses. It is just after last 'FEATURE'.

I tried your expression in a quick browser compiler and does not work. Last 'FEATURE' name should be mandatory.

Comment: Hello, it's true that this regexp is supposed to match the blocks, but when I use it into my java file it just gets overflow and there are no apparent changes to the target files.

Comment: Maybe exception is caused by the size of file you are parsing.

Comment: Any solution for it ?

Comment: Can you post it so that I can try, please?

Comment: still getting a monstruous overflow

Comment: The file is not larger than 1 MB, that's why, I wonder where is overflow error coming from . . .

Comment: Try with a smaller file first, if works you can be sure it is the file size. So just try **UPDATE 2** solution.

Comment: Thanks. May also suggest to remove all your the comments are "un-necessary". Just to avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: I have been trying to implement this dependancies that you linked (largetext) but I don't have Access to internet in this computer by security measures. Do you have an Idea how can I implement these packets into my JavaScript Project?

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:***

I tried implementing the solution of Wiktor:

```
"^#ifdef "+patterns.get(i)+"((?:\\r?\\n(?!#endif (?:// end of )?"+patterns.get(i)+"$).*)*)\\r?\\n#endif (?:// end of )?"+patterns.get(i)+"$"
```

and it captures only the second block, but not the following one:

> **#ifdef FEATURE**
>
> **Junk captured text**
>
> **#endif // end of FEATURE**

Anyway, when I run the jar still getting overflow.